# Function without final argument, which includes Runnable()

Tags: java, android

How to create function without final argument, which includes Runnable()?

```
 public void scroll(int scroll_to) {
        final HorizontalScrollView scrl = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
        scrl.post(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                 scrl.scrollTo(0, scroll_to);
            } 
        });
    }
```

But this cannot refer to non-final `scroll_to` variable. How to do universal function to scroll? Without `Runnable` it does not always work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
public void scroll(int scroll_to)
{
    final int x = scroll_to;
    final HorizontalScrollView scrl = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    scrl.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            scrl.scrollTo(0, x);
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value of `scrl` to your runnable during construction time, instead of referencing it from your runnable.

```
protected class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    protected HorizontalScrollView scrl;

    public SetStatusIconRunnable( HorizontalScrollView scrl, int scrollTo ) {
        mScrl = val;
                    mScrollTo = scrollTo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mScrl.scrollTo(0, mScrollTo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `scroll_to` final. It works on method arguments too.